# How to move my IBM api connect service from my mac to an Ubuntu server

Tags: ibm-cloud, loopbackjs

I have built a working IBM api connect service (loopback) that provides local mySQL data to/from an angular website.  I now want to move this service to an Ubuntu web server (appache) so that I can open up the website to external traffic. I have moved installed api connect onto the server and moved the project files across.

But I don't understand how to run the project so that it is available externally.  When I run API connect the api is available on a local port address: Web server listening at: http://127.0.0.1:9000.

But in my webpage (angularjs) I can't call this as it tries to connect on the client machine, not server.

Has anyone done this before and if so, can you offer any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You should configure your Apache as a reverse proxy, so that it forwards requests from your public ip address at port 80 (or 443 if you want SSL) to localhost:9000. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html or https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/ if you'd like to try out Nginx.

Comment: i seem to have it working - I opened up the port 4001: So instead of: http://127.0.0.1:4001/api/taskSequences?filter[where][usertestmoduleid]=25 I now have http://my.ip.address:4001/api/taskSequences?filter[where][usertestmoduleid]=25. Does that make sense to you?  Are the two addresses equivalent, one is just a local address and the other is external?

Comment: Hard to say without more details. Is my.ip.address a public ip address? If so, you could make your web server listen on my.ip.address:80.

Comment: Yes it is a public IP address. Why 80?

Comment: It won't be widely available unless it listens on either 80 or 443 (standard http ports). Other ports might be filtered out by firewalls and therefore some users won't be able to reach your application.